# Exact Duplicate Closure -- Error

Tags: support

I recently posted a question about technical writing and after accepting answer I was happy with, I opened a new question focused specifically on journalism rather than technical writing (the prior topic) however my question was closed as an "exact duplicate" and I wanted to know if that validity could be checked since I specifically said in the technical writing question that I was going to post a question on journalism in a separate thread.

The link is at:  https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/breaking-into-tech-journalism-where-to-start-from-a-programming-background

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where is the difference between breaking into tech writing and into tech journalism? Maybe start with "writing" and "journalism". Could be that Writers.SE is the wrong site to ask the question, but for now I just do not know what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two questions read very similarly.  If you would like the second re-opened please edit it to refer to the first via link and then ask an obviously distinct question, clarifying the points of difference.  Once this is done it can be re-opened.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that mistake. I'll try making the changes as soon as I get the chance.